# RestKit with Core Data: Use NSPersistentStore with RestKit RKObjectManager

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, nspersistentstore

I am using RestKit with Core Data. Till now I initialized RestKit as following:

```
[...]
RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURLString:@"http://URL"];
objectManager.objectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore objectStoreWithStoreFilename:@"database.sql"];
[...]
```

without this xcode auto-generated Core Data properties:

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
```

Fetching data worked through calling objectsWithFetchRequest: in NSManagedObject. Now I would like to use NSFetchingResultsController and therefore I need at least such a managedObjectContext. But wherefrom do I get this managedObjectContext? My first idea was: from the auto-generated managedObjectContext in AppDelegate.m, but this 3 properties managedObjectContext, managedObjectModel and persistentStoreCoordinator are all depending on each other.

How can I "link" RestKit to Core Data correctly? How can I "link" a persistentStoreCoordinator to RestKit and the RKObjectManager?

Answer (score 0):

You are already linking RestKit and Core Data with that code. Now, if I understand the question, you just need to be able to get access to the managed object context. Try creating a "Core Data Manager" object that contains all of the code required for the context, model and store coordinator with those properties. Then any of your classes that require that code can just inherit from the core data manager.

Comment: What do you mean with a "Core Data Manager" object? Is this a specific class? I probably found what I am looking for: 
NSManagedObjectContext* context = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].objectStore managedObjectContextForCurrentThread]; to get the managedObjectContext. Is this correct?

Comment: When I set up my app, there was a bunch of core data code associated to those properties that was auto-generated. I just moved that code into a custom object and reused it where I needed it. However, that might also be a solution for you

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer at http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/advanced-restkit-development_iphone-sdk/

RKManagedObjectStore – The object store wraps the initialization and configuration of internal Core Data classes including NSManagedObjectModel, NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, and NSManagedObjectContext.

RestKit handles the "link" to Core Data quiet autonomous. There are no linkings to do.

Getting a NSFetchingResultsController is possible through a NSManagedObject calling the fetchAllSortedBy or a similar method in NSManagedObject+ActiveRecord.h. e.g.

```
fetchedResultsController = [Customer fetchAllSortedBy:@"surname" ascending:YES withPredicate:nil groupBy:@"surname"];
```